# Swift: cellForRowAtIndexPath not called in the order of indexPaths

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

At first the indexpath are called in sequence of 0,1,2... but after clicking on the table view , the func tablview is called with indexpath that seems completely random , and hence i am unable to reproduce the same data . I am using array to correlate the rows of the table .

The code is here:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  myList.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
// Configure the cell...

    println("table view --> ")
    let CellID : NSString = "Cell"
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID)as UITableViewCell
     var VehicleName = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
     var VehicleNumber = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel

     if let ip = indexPath
     {

        VehicleName.text = arrayData[ip.row*2];
        VehicleNumber.text = arrayData[ip.row*2+1];
    }
 }
     return cell

 }
```

Comment: Why do you expect order for indexPaths? Also, you mention lot of wrong function names here. Please be clear on what you want to achieve here, what have you tried so far, and what is not working.

Comment: I am fetching data from arrayData and using indexPath to get data serially . So when cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called in the sequence as earlier , i am getting random data displayed on table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a design problem. You need to be able to supply the data as requested in a random access fashion.

Study the documentation on UITableView and `UITableViewDataSource'.

The API calls cellForRowAtIndexPath as it needs the data, it just requests the data that it needs to display, not all the data each time. It only creates the cells that are being displayed. If you had 1000 rows of data and were displaying rows 900 through say 903 it only needs that data. If the view scrolls to display one more row it only needs more data from row 904.

Comment: Thanks . I will probably try to change the dependencies on my array .

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no guarantee in what order of indexPaths `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called. It is upon the UIKit framework.

You need to, and can, fully control how your data source array holds data. In this case, it is `arrayData` - I also have a feeling that this is in some way related to `myList`, but it is not visible from your code snippet. Work on how elements are arranged within arrayData and then you will have expected elements in all cells.

Comment: thanks , will try to make it independent of my array .